# Best self-study books for static mechanics problems

Tags: resource-recommendations, statics

Which book is the best for me to self-study/improve at static mechanics problems?

I am looking for a book with a lot of ( only ) problems, not a theoretical book.

Not only basic problems, the ideal is a book with a lot of problems going from easy to hard.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you go for [this](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP003197.html) one:

**Engineering Mechanics: Statics, 8th Edition** by *James L. Meriam, L. G. Kraige, J. N. Bolton*

[image]

Comment: Also do read the highlighted message just below the original post: **Answers containing only a reference to a book or paper will be removed!**

Comment: Oh okay. I'd take care of that.